# kubernetes role hidden one secret

Tags: kubernetes

I need to set one secret resource to be inaccessible but the other secrets in the namespace to be available
k8s is 1.24
Try:

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: Role
metadata:
  name: secret-access
  namespace: namespace1
rules:
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["secrets"]
  resourceNames: ["secret-to-be-inaccessible"]
  verbs: ["list", "watch"]
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["secrets"]
  verbs: ["get", "list", "watch"]
  resourceNames: ["*"]
```

Answer (score 0):

As per this [doc](https://www.weave.works/blog/kubernetes-authorization)

> Once you create a role, you need to define which actions the Entity
> can execute. They can be classified into:
>
> **Read-only:** where the entity cannot modify the resource. The verbs get and list.
>
> **Read-write**: where
> the entity can modify the resource. The verbs that fall into this
> category are create, update, delete, and delete collections.

Can you try the below yaml, where i have changed the verbs for resource names : secrets-to-be-inaccessible.

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: Role
metadata:
  name: secret-access
  namespace: namespace1
rules:
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["secrets"]
  resourceNames: ["secret-to-be-inaccessible"]
  verbs: ["get", "list"]
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["secrets"]
  verbs: ["get", "list", "watch"]
  resourceNames: ["*"]
```

By using these secrets it's not -possible to hide or inaccessible the secret but we keep that particular secret in read only  mode but not read-write mode.

You can also refer to this official docs [Request verb](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authorization/#determine-the-request-verb) , [RBAC Authorization](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authorization/#determine-the-request-verb)